# Why Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1 cannot use ip number to connect server?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1 can only be accessed by host 127.0.0.1, but cannot be accessed by ip number. What may be the reason for this problem? I checked and made sure that firewall was turned off, and I also tried but could not connect IoTDB with the cli tool using ip number. Does anyone know how I can connect to IoTDB using ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if you have changed all your configuration files to Version `1.0.1` of Apache IoTDB. Seems like this problem may be caused by the error of configuration settings.